# How to match a wiremock POST request with some optional JSON parameters & any values?

Tags: wiremock

I need to use wiremock to test a POST request that's sending data like this:

```
{
    "name": "known fixed value",
    "dateOfBirth": 5123456789000,
    "email": "known fixed value",
    "currentDate": any numeric value,
    "status": any text value with alphabets, numbers and symbols
}
```

The 1st 3 fields, name, dateOfBirth and email are fixed, known values, that don't change from one request to the next.

The last 2 fields, currentDate and status change randomly from one request to the next, but are mandatory fields that can hold any value.

How do I design a mapping that tests this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [JsonPath regex request body matcher](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#regex-matching), for example in your case you should use this JsonPath:

```
$[?(@.name == 'known fixed value' && @.dateOfBirth == 5123456789000 && @.email == 'known fixed value' && @.currentDate =~ /[0-9]*/i && @.status =~ /.*/i)]
```

Which will match an example request body:

```
{
"name": "known fixed value",
"dateOfBirth": 5123456789000,
"email": "known fixed value",
"currentDate": 23123,
"status": "rfjhg33443"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use JSON stubbing, you can write

```
  "request": {
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "equalToJson": {
          "name": "known fixed value",
          "dateOfBirth": 5123456789000,
          "email": "known fixed value",
          "currentDate": "${json-unit.any-number}",
          "status": "${json-unit.any-string}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Ref: section "Placeholders" in http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/