# How to verify optional parameters using Wiremock Request Matching Stubs(JAVA Usage)?

Tags: java, wiremock

[How to match a wiremock POST request with some optional JSON parameters & any values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019382/how-to-match-a-wiremock-post-request-with-some-optional-json-parameters-any-va)

Being new to Stack community, I have raised the below query(afraid that it would be marked as duplicate) in the post (link mentioned above) but it has been deleted stating its the different question and need to raise new question.

Below is my query on top of it:

If the optional parameter is not present in the request than the solution provided in the above post suffice the purpose.

But If the optional parameter is present and we need to check that it contains specific values only (say not null) then how to do that using request matching in [wiremock](/questions/tagged/wiremock).

Kindly provide your inputs as I am new to [wiremock](/questions/tagged/wiremock)

For instance:

```
{
"optional1"="ValueAlwaysYESIfPresent",
"optional2"="ValueAlwaysNOIfPresent"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/
instead of going to other places
basically you can do matching like

```
withQueryParam("optional2", equalTo("ValueAlwaysNOIfPresent"))
```

Or

```
 withQueryParam("optional2", matching(".*12345.*"))
```

and many other things.

Comment: Its not query parameter rather coming in request body alongwith other mandatory parameters. (If you have checked the link attached in the question). Anyways i had been found the workaround for it.